# Unable to receive response from HTTP Post request to C# Web API from Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I'm having a C# Web API application hosted at a certain domain.
Using postman all web api's work as expected, including in the application consuming it.

Now I'm having a scenario where in **I need to issue a POST request to the *hosted C# Web API* from a *C# Windows Application***.

I've tried Google(ing) this issue and am able to find only partial solution to my problem.

When I call my webapi using Postman; this is the actual/required JSON response that I get:

```
{
    "access_token": "7oIHQgUyb4NJc-kAc4Ce7Xa1ly5vKCaoxh0w-3PDixpvZtJkBLy7dg6kyE0gp_EZ_9pmh7LC06ztBKNyLbpLcruV9uHEVvIrvKvt0zowUv3Ho9sDGddvGy808N_tliljM8HYe4wJlcwlE9VzlWEv7bz3CNRNj_o9WLqPjcRTu2LN9wMAyMSXGdI_rE2guw-1w1W6aoDgr71x61InbRJ_DNqNpH0MhIUprhTeEVh59WEaq76FLErHTo3TXUTcjximVlxHQPZWh0gWN3dX7sI_Wz60RUK_h4SZO2VZ3QWZivPXX8CsOlXaullq0MnSLogb",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 28799,
    "Username": "Gomesdenver",
    "UserId": "490253d0-79f6-4aed-96a9-5a041375d84c",
    "Role": "3b55f063-eb24-4e76-b30d-c2509c37fd8a",
    "DisplayAY": "2019-2020"
}
```

Please see image below (Postman request's response is what I'm seeking):
[image: Interested in JSON response herein]

My C# Windows Code is as below:

```
public async Task<string> LoginUser(string Username, string Password, Notifier notification)
{
    string strResult = string.Empty;
    dynamic res;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        notification("Attempting to contact database. Please wait..");
        await Task.Delay(750);

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("username", "GomesDenver");
        dict.Add("password", "MyPassword");
        dict.Add("grant_type", "password");

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://dummyuri.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "token")
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict)
        };

        res = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strResult = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    return strResult;
}
```

Everything works as expected; but I'm not able to fetch the response as in Postman.
The result that I get using this code is: 
[image: Result received]

I'm getting "OK" Status Code, but how can I access the JSON response from this request?
How can I get the token value in my C# Windows Application code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for the response headers? Why not use HttpResponseMessage rather than dynamic res?

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano I am not concerned with the headers or response headers. I want the Postman's response using my c# windows code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize the [HttpResponseMessage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage)

```
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Help appreciated @AnthonyLiriano. Your response helped me a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.. Great.